# How to do close join in Julia DataFrames?

Tags: r, julia, dataframes.jl

```
classA = Dataset(id = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5"],
                        mark = [50, 69.5, 45.5, 88.0, 98.5]);

grades = Dataset(mark = [0, 49.5, 59.5, 69.5, 79.5, 89.5, 95.5],
                        grade = ["F", "P", "C", "B", "A-", "A", "A+"]);
```

we can use InMemorydatasets package to do closejoin.

How can we do this method in DataFrames package.

```
closejoin(classA, grades, on = :mark)
```

```
closejoin(classA, grades, on = :mark, direction=:forward, border=:nearest)
```

and how to do this in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In *R* it could be done by using `findInterval`.

```
classA = data.frame(id = c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5"),
                        mark = c(50, 69.5, 45.5, 88.0, 98.5))

grades = data.frame(mark = c(0, 49.5, 59.5, 69.5, 79.5, 89.5, 95.5),
                 grade = c("F", "P", "C", "B", "A-", "A", "A+"))

cbind(classA, grade = grades$grade[findInterval(classA$mark, grades$mark)])
#   id mark grade
#1 id1 50.0     P
#2 id2 69.5     B
#3 id3 45.5     F
#4 id4 88.0    A-
#5 id5 98.5    A+

cbind(classA, grade = grades$grade[findInterval(classA$mark, c(-Inf, grades$mark), all.inside = TRUE, left.open = TRUE)])
  id mark grade
#1 id1 50.0     C
#2 id2 69.5     B
#3 id3 45.5     P
#4 id4 88.0     A
#5 id5 98.5    A+
```

In Julia you can use `searchsortedlast` and `searchsortedfirst`.

```
using DataFrames

classA = DataFrame(id = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5"],
                   mark = [50, 69.5, 45.5, 88.0, 98.5]);
grades = DataFrame(mark = [0, 49.5, 59.5, 69.5, 79.5, 89.5, 95.5],
                   grade = ["F", "P", "C", "B", "A-", "A", "A+"]);

classA[!, "Grade"] = grades.grade[[searchsortedlast(grades.mark, x) for x in classA.mark]]
classA
#5×3 DataFrame
# Row │ id      mark     Grade  
#     │ String  Float64  String 
#─────┼─────────────────────────
#   1 │ id1        50.0  P
#   2 │ id2        69.5  B
#   3 │ id3        45.5  F
#   4 │ id4        88.0  A-
#   5 │ id5        98.5  A+

classA[!, "Grade"] =  grades.grade[min.(length(grades.grade), [searchsortedfirst(grades.mark, x) for x in classA.mark])]
classA
#5×3 DataFrame
# Row │ id      mark     Grade  
#     │ String  Float64  String 
#─────┼─────────────────────────
#   1 │ id1        50.0  C
#   2 │ id2        69.5  B
#   3 │ id3        45.5  P
#   4 │ id4        88.0  A
#   5 │ id5        98.5  A+
```

---

The same with `InMemoryDatasets` in *Julia* as given in the question including results for comparison.

```
using InMemoryDatasets

classA = Dataset(id = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5"],
                        mark = [50, 69.5, 45.5, 88.0, 98.5]);

grades = Dataset(mark = [0, 49.5, 59.5, 69.5, 79.5, 89.5, 95.5],
                 grade = ["F", "P", "C", "B", "A-", "A", "A+"]);

closejoin(classA, grades, on = :mark)
#5×3 Dataset
# Row │ id        mark      grade    
#     │ identity  identity  identity 
#     │ String?   Float64?  String?  
#─────┼──────────────────────────────
#   1 │ id1           50.0  P
#   2 │ id2           69.5  B
#   3 │ id3           45.5  F
#   4 │ id4           88.0  A-
#   5 │ id5           98.5  A+

closejoin(classA, grades, on = :mark, direction=:forward, border=:nearest)
#5×3 Dataset
# Row │ id        mark      grade    
#     │ identity  identity  identity 
#     │ String?   Float64?  String?  
#─────┼──────────────────────────────
#   1 │ id1           50.0  C
#   2 │ id2           69.5  B
#   3 │ id3           45.5  P
#   4 │ id4           88.0  A
#   5 │ id5           98.5  A+
```

Answer (score 4):

As `InMemoryDatasets` is a Julia package, and composability is a Julia highlight, getting `DataFrames` to do `closejoin` can be done with some connecting code. Admittedly this is not super efficient, but `InMemoryDatasets` code works, and reusing it saves some development time.

Specifically, the following:

```
using DataFrames, InMemoryDatasets

import Base: pairs

pairs(d::DataFrame) = zip(Symbol.(names(d)), eachcol(d))
pairs(d::Dataset) = zip(Symbol.(names(d)), eachcol(d))

function df_closejoin(f1::DataFrame, f2::DataFrame; kwargs...)
    f1ds = Dataset(Dict(pairs(f1)))
    f2ds = Dataset(Dict(pairs(f2)))
    resds = InMemoryDatasets.closejoin(f1ds, f2ds; kwargs...)
    return DataFrame(Dict(pairs(resds)))
end
```

Allows:

```
julia> df_closejoin(classA, grades, on = :mark)
5×3 DataFrame
 Row │ grade    id       mark     
     │ String?  String?  Float64? 
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │ P        id1          50.0
   2 │ B        id2          69.5
   3 │ F        id3          45.5
   4 │ A-       id4          88.0
   5 │ A+       id5          98.5

julia> df_closejoin(classA, grades, on = :mark,
                 direction=:forward, border=:missing)
5×3 DataFrame
 Row │ grade    id       mark     
     │ String?  String?  Float64? 
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │ C        id1          50.0
   2 │ B        id2          69.5
   3 │ P        id3          45.5
   4 │ A        id4          88.0
   5 │ missing  id5          98.5
```

When both `classA` and `grades` are now DataFrames defined by:

```
classA = DataFrame(id = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5"],
                   mark = [50, 69.5, 45.5, 88.0, 98.5]);
grades = DataFrame(mark = [0, 49.5, 59.5, 69.5, 79.5, 89.5, 95.5],
                   grade = ["F", "P", "C", "B", "A-", "A", "A+"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

One potential solution is to use [RCall](https://github.com/JuliaInterop/RCall.jl) and [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html), e.g. in R:

```r
library(data.table)

classA <- structure(list(id = c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5"), 
                         mark = c(50, 69.5, 45.5, 88, 98.5)), 
                    class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))

classB <- structure(list(mark = c(0, 49.5, 59.5, 69.5, 79.5, 89.5, 95.5),
                         grade = c("F", "P", "C", "B", "A-", "A", "A+")),
                    class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))

setkey(classA, mark)
setkey(classB, mark)
classB[classA, roll=+Inf][order(id)]
#>    mark grade  id
#> 1: 50.0     P id1
#> 2: 69.5     B id2
#> 3: 45.5     F id3
#> 4: 88.0    A- id4
#> 5: 98.5    A+ id5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>